# Using Xj3D in a Java code application

Tags: java, x3d

I'm creating a java application on Netbeans and I've done research into how to import X3D models into java applications and the one that people have been saying is to us Xj3D, but I've not seen how to use Xj3D and how to use it with java.

My application is to view the X3D models in the java project and any help on how to use Xj3D in Netbeans would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The xj3d project site contains a [tutorials](http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/index.html) section where you will find an introductory tutorial that shows, among other things, how to add a browser component to a GUI and then [load a scene](http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/general_sai.html#LoadFile).

The following code does exactly that:

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(null);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Component browserComponent = (Component) x3dComponent.getImplementation();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(browserComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] {"test.x3dv"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It loads a "test.x3dv" file which can contain anything you like. I suggest something simple for your initial experiments, such as (a rotating cube):

```
#X3D V3.0 utf8

PROFILE Interactive

DEF TS TimeSensor {
  cycleInterval 3
  loop TRUE
}

DEF TG Transform {
  rotation 0 1 0 0
  children Shape {
    geometry Box {}
    appearance Appearance {
      material DEF MAT Material {
        diffuseColor 1 0 0
      }
    }
  }
}

DEF OI OrientationInterpolator {
  key [ 0 0.5 1 ]
  keyValue [
     0 1 0 0
     0 1 0 3.14
     0 1 0 6.28
  ]
}

ROUTE TS.fraction_changed TO OI.set_fraction
ROUTE OI.value_changed TO TG.rotation
```

To compile/run this (with Netbeans or otherwise) you will need to:

- place all xj3d jars, found under the jars subdirectory of your xj3d directory, on the classpath (create a new library in Netbeans to do that),
- specify the -Djava.library.path VM argument so as to contain the full path to the bin subdirectory of your xj3d directory (otherwise you will get a "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path" exception).

I suggest you download and use the latest [dev release](http://www.xj3d.org/snapshots.html) (but note that it hasn't been updated since 2010).

Comment: How would I find the Xj3D jars? :)

Comment: Like I said, there should be a "jars" subdirectory in the directory where xj3d is installed. The tutorials section of the website describes this and other bits of useful information on [using xj3d in your java application](http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/xj3d_application.html).